# Override Ajax Success event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to override the jQuery `ajax` function to handle a default action on a success event but also executing the callback function that i am using in the `options` parameter.
What the purpose is there is tags returning in the response that I always want to strip out of the response for use elsewhere.

The scenario is:

- Ajax submit
- Ajax Success
- --DEFAULT SUCCESS ACTION
- --Call Ajax Success Callback

Can anyone help?
I have tried extending

- `jQuery.ajax`
- `jQuery.ajaxSuccess`
- `jQuery.ajax.done`

The code I have is:

```
var _ajaxSuccess = jQuery.fn.ajaxSuccess;  
$.fn.extend({  
    ajaxSuccess: function (a)  
    {  
        _ajaxSuccess.apply(this, a);  
    }  
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the global [`ajaxSuccess`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) callback:

> Whenever an Ajax request completes successfully, jQuery triggers the `ajaxSuccess` event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with the `.ajaxSuccess()` method are executed at this time.

That will let you call your own function on every successful AJAX call without interfering with the usual success callbacks.

There are various other [global AJAX event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) that you might want to look at too.

If those callbacks don't have the right timing or capabilities for you, then you could write your own wrapper for `$.ajax` and use that:

```
function wrapped_ajax(options) {
    var success = options.success;
    options.success = function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // Do whatever needs to be done here.
        if(success)
            success(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
    };
    return $.ajax(options);
}
```

You can do whatever you need to the usual success callback parameters before calling the original success callback. You'd call `wrapped_ajax` in exactly the same way as `$.ajax`. You could use the same technique to hook into the other callbacks as well.

Comment: Cheers these are along the lines of what i am looking for but they fire too late for me. i want to catch the response strip out what i need and then use the call back functionality.

Comment: @Qpirate: I added an update that might get the job done. Just a simple wrapper for `$.ajax`. If necessary, you might be able to monkey patch your jQuery to use your `wrapper_ajax` in place of its own but some care would be needed and I wouldn't advise it.

Comment: this solved the problem perfectly, thanks so much been working on this for the last few days.

Comment: Here is another article on this topic: http://www.svlada.com/blog/override-jquery-ajax-handler/

Answer (score 2):

try `jQuery.ajaxSetup` it may help you ,read about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup)

Comment: thanks @Miroprocessor but this is just the defaults and my success functionality will override it. but you may have given me an idea on how to do it. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
$.ajaxSuccess(function(){
    //somethingtodo
});
```

Mentioned in http://tutorialzine.com/2011/06/15-powerful-jquery-tips-and-tricks-for-developers/ heading twelve.