# how to call function on global ajaxSuccess() - errorhandling http-header

Tags: jquery, ajax, global

although I found a lot of matches when searching I do not really find a proper solution my problem: 
In my script I have a whole lot of AJAX-Requests. In many requests I execute important codesnippets within

```
$ajax{.. success: //code here.. }.
```

Now I need to validate a special `http-response-header` in order to handle errors `serverside` with every success. I don't think it would be very elegant to call a function `handleHeaderFieldXYZ()` in every single Request. How could I define a global handler like (ajaxSuccess, which is just callable for `$(elem)`)? If I defined a success in my Ajax-Setup I would overwrite it when calling the defined local successes.

Answer (score 1):

I wrapped the jQuery AJAX Request/Response mechanisms and implemented deferred objects.

So when a request is made i can work with a function called:

- .done:  Request success handler
- .fail:  Request failure handler

I did this so as to implement generic handlers for certain Request errors and to allow me to make AJAX requests and supply a function to handle the response in an easier less polluting fashion.

I still need to work a little more on the code, but the basic principle is the implementation of AJAX can be removed with another implementation as long as the standardized result is kept in place.  This means that another developer can use the wrapper to implement his/her own AJAX implementation and all the logic across the systems should still work.

This code could work for you with your scenario if I understand your problem correctly.  This is not perfect yet and you can improve on it I am sure but I hope it helps.

The only thing I can think of that may be missing for you is the AJAX Request Object to work with the headers.  I think it is accessible in .done/.fail otherwise you can just pass it on so that you can do your evaluation.

Following is the JavaScript logic to make a call to the AJAX wrapper:

```
AJAXHandler.MakeServiceRequest("POST", serviceUrl, method, queryString, jsonFilterArgument)
    .done(function (requestResult) {
        // Handle Request Success
        if (requestResult.Data.Quote) {
            var quote = requestResult.Data.Quote;
            // handle quote
        } else {
            // handle no quote found
        }
        return this;
    })
    .fail(function () {
        // handle Request Failure
        return this;
    });
```

Following is the AJAX wrapper:

```
var jqueryAJAXHandler = function ($) {

    // private
    function ResponseHandler(data) {
        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        var obj;

        if (data.d) {
            obj = JSON.parse(data.d, JSON.IsoDateReviver); // we use iso standard for date transmission hence the isoDateReviver.
        } else {
            obj = JSON.parse(data, JSON.IsoDateReviver); // we use iso standard for date transmission hence the isoDateReviver.
        }

        if (obj === null || obj.RequestStatus === null) {
            // Every request made must respond with a requestStatus object as per standards.
            // If obj is null it means that requestStatus was not added to the response OR
            // an error occurred while chatting to the other server.
            var failResult = {
                RequestStatus: {
                    Status: 'error',
                    Type: 'malformedResponse',
                    Message: 'No Request Status object returned.'
                }
            };

            dfd.reject(failResult);
            return dfd.promise();
        }
        else if (obj.RequestStatus.Status === "error") {
            // Everything is in order up to this point.
            // we are now looking at a well formed response.
            // we just do not know if the request for processing
            // was successful.
            // We now look at the requestStatus object to figure
            // out if we were successful in proceessing.

            // ACCESS RIGHTS or INVALID SESSION error handler
            if (obj.RequestStatus.Type === "invalidSession") {
                dfd.reject(null); // close off current deferred object.
                return HelpejqueryAJAXHandlerr.GenericInvalidSessionHandler(obj); // return different promise.
            }
            else if (obj.RequestStatus.Type === "noAccess") {
                dfd.reject(null); // close off current deferred object.
                return jqueryAJAXHandler.GenericNoAccessHandler(obj); // return different promise.
            }

            dfd.reject(obj);
            return dfd.promise(); // all other errors are handled by custom error handlers.
        }

        dfd.resolve(obj);
        return dfd.promise();
    }

    // public
    return {
        GenericInvalidSessionHandler: function () {
            window.location.href = obj.RequestStatus.Url;
            return null;
        },
        GenericNoAccessHandler: function (obj) {
            var dfd = $.Deferred();
            // TODO : Implement generic no access rights error handler
            // must work accross any page.
            dfd.reject(obj);
            return dfd.promise();
        },
        GenericErrorHandler: function (obj) {
            var dfd = $.Deferred();
            alert("An error occurred while processing your request.  Please try again.  If this issue continues please inform your manager.");
            dfd.reject(obj);
            return dfd.promise();
        },

        MakeServiceRequest: function (requestType, serviceURL, methodName, queryString, objData) {
            var dfd = $.Deferred();

            //#region MakeServiceRequest

            // ORGANISE THE ARGUMENTS FOR THE REQUEST.
            // ensure the session id always goes through.
            var args = ""; 
            var blnProcessData = false;
            // convert arguments into JSON string for $.ajax request.
            // arguments come after the 4 reqd parameters

            //args = 
            // PROCESS URL
            // put href into loc var for easy reading.
            var loc = serviceURL + "/" + methodName;
            if (queryString != "") {
                loc = loc + "?" + queryString; //window.location.href;
            }

            // CALL WEB METHOD
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                async: true,
                type: requestType,
                url: loc,
                data: objData,
                processData: blnProcessData,
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json"
            })
                .success(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    ResponseHandler(data)
                        .done(function (obj) {
                            dfd.resolve(obj);
                        })
                        .fail(function (obj) {
                            dfd.reject(obj);
                        });
                })
                .error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // XMLHttpRequest Failed.
                    var failResult = {
                        RequestStatus: {
                            Status: 'error',
                            Type: textStatus,
                            Message: errorThrown
                        }
                    };
                    dfd.reject(failResult);
                });

            return dfd.promise();
            //#endregion MakeServiceRequest
        }
    }
};          // jqueryAJAXHandler
```

Comment: wow, thank you very much for this detailed answer! i definitely will adopt that in future.

Comment: No problem. I hope it sorts out your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another post which could be a simple approach to your problem ...

[Override Ajax Success event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532186/override-ajax-success-event)

You can then inside that function add the current event after the handlerHeaderFieldXYZ()
as you have mentioned above

Comment: Hey, thanks for the Link, but i do not really get into it: Somenone mentioned to try $.ajaxSuccess(function(){//code}); which I tried too, but it doesn't work! Firebug tells me that it is not a function :-( (also using jQuery instead of $). Any idea why?

Comment: if think it might be `$.fn.ajaxSuccess = function (){ ... $.fn.ajaxSuccess(); }` not sure thought but worth a try/check

Comment: I do not dare to say that this found: Ajax settings http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ global:false! So I have a global handler and when I do not want to call it during a local one, I set global:false for the local one.. So I worked around.