# Cannot redirect inside the custom success callback on an Ajax wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying redirect a user to the login page if he/she is not logged in anymore or do not have the permission when doing certain functionalities via Ajax. To not get redundant, I implemented a wrapper for the success callback based on the code that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6532321) that checks if the controller returned not_logged_in to signify that the user does not have permission. If the user doesn't have permission, I redirect the user using the custom success function. **The problem is that it doesn't redirect the user to the login page. Instead, it just prints the login page on the console and the actual Ajax call fails.** What should I change in my code?

Here is the Ajax wrapper:

```
function wrapped_ajax(options) {
    var success = options.success;
    options.success = function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if(success) {
            if (data.not_logged_in) {
                window.location = 'login';
            } else {
                success(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
            }
        }

    };
    return $.ajax(options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location.href='http://'+document.domain+'/login'` (or similar to create proper url) instead.

Comment: Same results. It still just prints the login page on the console.

Comment: Don't you get any error? Trying to reproduce the problem at jsfiddle led me to error of trying to load mixed content.

Comment: I haven't gotten any errors on my console. It just calls the error callback of Ajax.

Comment: Have you tried `window.location.replace("/login")`?

Comment: It did not work either. I think the problem is that the custom success callback passes the login page to the actual Ajax call which results in an Ajax error. I am not sure how to fix it though.

Comment: And how about `window.location.reload()`?

Comment: Still doesn't work. I think the problem is that the custom success callback passes the login page to the actual Ajax call which results in an Ajax error. I am not sure how to fix it though.